# Automated Login for Firewall

Tags: bash, authentication, curl, post

I have a firewall login window with url like `http://192.168.51.1:1000/fgtauth?434a5d67b6a5efe8`. This window needs inputs such as `username` and `password` applying which a keepalive window will be loaded and the internet can be accessed. I am using Ubuntu.

How to create a bash file which looks if the firewall is authenticated, and if it is not then authenticate with predefined credentials, and repeat this in each `3600 seconds`. The firewall authentication is unique each time. If firewall is not authenticated other url's like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) redirects to firewall page.

I have seen results like this:https://yashsriv.org/posts/firewall-auth/. Can this be modified to work in my scenario?

Comment: You can use curl -I to check the headers for http error codes such as 401 for unauthorised access